# Does the set of vectors (2,-1) and (1,3) span all of R^2?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is this the correct way to approach the problem?

step 1: $a(2,-1) + b(1,3) = (x, y)$

step 2: 2a + b = x
        -a + 3b = y

step 3: solve for a and b

are these the correct steps that i have to take in order to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

See if the two vectors are linearly independent or not!

If this $a(2,-1) + b(1,3) = (0, 0)$ holds then check if $a$ and $b$ are both zero or not.

Answer (score 1):

That’s certainly one way to approach the problem: If you can find any solution at all, then you’ve shown that an arbitrary vector $(x,y)$ can be written as a linear combination of the two given vectors.

For this problem and others like it, you can take some short-cuts. A pair of vectors is linearly independent iff one is a scalar multiple of the other. That’s obviously not the case here. We also know that the span of set of $k$ linearly-independent vectors is $k$-dimensional, so the span of our two vectors is two-dimensional. Finally, the only two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ is itself.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. But i just need to know, do the vectors span all of R^2? i still haven't found the answer to this problem

Comment: @Soon_to_be_code_master I direct your attention to the last sentence above: “The only two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ is itself.” The vectors span a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^2$, therefore... ?

Comment: ..therefore it does span all of R^2. Sorry its just that this is my first time learning the concept of vector spaces and subspaces, it all seems confusing to me